# Widgets can not be centered

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an alarm tool here but as a begginer i have some difficulties to over come.So, one of them is to align a couple of my widgets in the center of red frame (top_left_fr) but i can't figure it out. Any help?

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from time import strftime
    
def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    lbl.config(text=string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)


window = Tk()
window.geometry("700x400")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

top_left_fr = Frame(window, bg="red", width=500, height=250)
top_left_fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S, columnspan=5)

left_bottom_fr = Frame(window, bg="blue", width=500, height=150, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black")
left_bottom_fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + S)

right_fr = Frame(window, bg="green", width=200, height=400, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black")
right_fr.grid(row=0, column=1)

time_lbl = Label(top_left_fr, text="REAL TIME", font=('calibri', 20, 'bold'))
time_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 0))

add_but = Button(top_left_fr, text="Αdd")
add_but.grid(row=3, column=3)

lbl = Label(top_left_fr, font=('calibri', 20, 'bold'),
            background='black',
            foreground='white')

lbl.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10)
time()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: I think  it's fine now.Sorry by the way!

Comment: There's still a problem with the formatting. Also, you said _"one of them is to align a couple of my widgets"_ - what does "a couple" mean? Which widgets specifically are you wanting to center, and are you wanting them centered horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: So i want the label time_lbl to be centered  horizontally in the first row ,label lbl to be centered horizontally in second row and button add_but to be centered horizontally in the third row. These actions have to happen in the red frame top_left_fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that requires the least amount of code would be to use `pack` instead of `grid`. By default, `pack` will center the widget along the side it was placed.

You'll also need to adjust the red frame so that it doesn't overlap the green frame by removing `columnspan` when you add that frame.

```
top_left_fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)
...
time_lbl.pack(side="top", fill="x")
lbl.pack(side="top", fill="x")
add_but.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

If you want to use `grid`, you need to make sure that the column that contains the widgets is configured to expand to fill any additional space. By default, `grid` will center the widgets in the allocated space. As with `pack`, you need to remove `columnspan` when adding the red frame.

```
top_left_fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)
top_left_fr.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
time_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
add_but.grid(row=2, column=0)
```